# Deregister delegated class

Tags: java, oop

I have decided to use composition to extend functionality of several Service classes we have in a project by adding a security layer to prevent calling method. All was fine until I found a class that registers itself as a listener to another service and I see I'll need to also extend the method called in the listener. This listener is registered in the init method of this class so I thought I could 'de-register' the delegated class after its init method has been called and register instead my composited class but I feel it's a bit dirty... I would like to know what do you think about this approach or how would you solve this.

Maybe you can have a better idea looking at an example of the classes I have:

```
public abstract class ServiceAbs {
    protected void init();
}

public interface OldClassIF {
    public void aMethod();
}

public MyOldClass extends ServiceAbs implements OldClassIF, ListenerIF {
    protected void init() {
        Observer.addListener(this);
        //Other stuff needed
    }

    public void onListener() {
    }
    @Override
    public void aMethod() {
    }

}

public MyNewClass extends ServiceAbs implements OldClassIF, ListenerIF {
    MyOldClass oldClass;
    public void onListener() {
       if(condition) {
           oldClass.onListener();
       }
    }
    protected void init() {
        oldClass.init();
        Observer.removeListener(oldClass);
        Observer.addListener(this);
    }
    public void aMethod() {
        if(condition) {
            oldClass.aMethod();
        }
    }
}
```